# ASP.NET MVC forbid access after form was submited

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am building a survey where customers are sent a direct link with an id that relates to the database so we can know who the customer is without them having to fill in their personal information. I based it off the Edit scaffolding since the row is precreated in the database and only needs to be edited to fill in the questions.

For clarity, the url is mydomain.com/controller/action/id -> where id is the PK of the row that holds the answers to the survey.

The issue I'm facing is that if they visit the direct link again they can edit the survey as many times as they want. I want to make it so once it is submitted the link leads to page that says "survey already submitted"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options ahead of you. Effectively you want to disable the survey if it has been submitted.

Two solutions I can think of are:

1. If the survey has already been filled out, don't let them edit it.
2. If you want the users to have the ability to edit a survey prior to submitting it, have a "SubmittedOn" Date field. If that field is populated, the Survey is complete and unable to be edited.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Boolean column to the row, and set it to true the first time the survey is submitted. In the method that loads the survey, check the value of this column before returning the view. If the value is true, redirect to another controller action, which lands the user to the 'Survey already submitted' page.